# Trying to get number of row and section of a text field in a cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, nsindexpath

I've a grouped `UITableView` with several custom cells where I placed text fields. I have defined a property pointing to the text field that is currently active:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   self.activeTextField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
   self.activeTextField = nil;
}
```

I need to get the row and section of the cell containing such text field. I tried this:

```
UITableViewCell *parentCell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.activeTextField superview];
NSIndexPath* cellPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:parentCell];
NSInteger cellRow = [cellPath row];
```

But I always get a 0. It looks like `parentCell` is not an `UITableViewCell` actually (but it should be). How can I get those values?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are adding the text view to cell's container view then you have to call `self.activeTextField.superview.superview`. If not, `self.activeTextField.superview` should work.

In order to find out if your text field is added to container view's cell:

1. If you add the text field from xib/storyboard to a custom cell then it is in contentView
2. If you do `[cell addSubview:]` then is in cell's view
3. If you do `[cell.cotentView addSubView:]` then is in container view.

Comment: I loaded my custom cells from a nib, and I placed the text field within the `UITableViewCell` view directly in Interface Builder. I tried with `self.activeTextField.superview.superview` and it worked, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Totally unsure if it works but you might try:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtPoint:[self.activeTextField center]];
```